# Checkboxes inside scrollable div are being shown outside of it

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

SO, I have a form with a list of checkboxes that is inside of a scrollable div. The problem is that what you see in the picture, the checkboxes are being shown outside the container.

http://image.prntscr.com/image/80494dcbb220424d94ebd3ba629c5698.png

Here's the code I have:

```
form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("id", "form_" + sensor + faceta);

document.getElementById(elementID).appendChild(form);

for (j = 0; j < valoresFaceta.length; j++) {

    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var description = document.createTextNode(valoresFaceta[j]);
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");

    checkbox.type = "checkbox";   
    checkbox.value = valoresFaceta[j];     


    label.appendChild(checkbox);  
    label.appendChild(description);
    document.getElementById("form_" + sensor + faceta).appendChild(label);
    document.getElementById("form_" + sensor + faceta).appendChild(document.createElement("br"));}
```

EDIT:
This is what I want but when I try to make this in JS the checkboxes that should be hidden are shown outside the container, can someone help?
https://jsfiddle.net/gtjarq09/

Answer (score 0):

You should show us the working example to fix it, but my guess is that you are setting the overflow: scroll property to the wrong block, try moving it to the parent block, or set overflow: hidden in the parent block

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is your checkbox position is **absolute**. When I had this issue, I was applying a custom style for my checkboxes which required me to hide the input element and set position to absolute.

The fix was to set the parent element to **position: relative** so that child elements will move as you scroll.